# Javascript: Return minutes in two digits?

Tags: javascript, time, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, minute

i am trying to write some Javascript for a Google Tag Manager variable that will return the number of minutes currently spent on a web page and then send that through to Google Analytics as an event.
Currently, the code below works, but it is returning anything below 10 minutes as a single digit, and anything below 100 minutes as double digits. I'd like to add leading zeros so that the minutes number is always 3 digits. I want to do this so I can sort events by minutes in GA, and have them sort in the correct time order. For example, I want one minute to be in the format "001m 0s" and twelve minutes to be in the format "012m 0s". Make sense? Here is the code I have currently:

```
function() {
var elapsed = {{timerEventNumber}} * {{timerInterval}} / 1000;
var min = Math.floor(elapsed/60);
var sec = elapsed % 60;
return min + 'm ' + sec + 's';
}
```

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the leading zeros, and create a substring from the last three characters of the string.

```
return ('00' + min).substr(-3) + 'm' + sec + 's';
```

[String.prototype.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)